# API request is undefined from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, command-line

I'm working on my first CLI project and I'm having trouble getting it to execute API requests. I have tried fetch, axios, express, and a couple of npm packages, but I just can't figure out what's wrong. The project will console.log and gather user data from the command line, but will not retrieve API data. I'm using a fake API data url at this point just to be sure it works. Here is the code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

let apiResponse;

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(function(response) {
    apiResponse = response;
    console.log('Does this work?')
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error, 'Error');
  });

console.log('apiResponse: ', apiResponse);
```

In the command line I get 'apiResponse:  undefined' when I run the file. Again, I've tried using several different libraries so I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. The console.log OUTSIDE of the function prints, but neither console.logs INSIDE are printing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing in your console you see

```
undefined
Does this work?
```

The `.get` method is asynchronous, which means any assignment outside of `then` will most likely always be what you initialize it as, in this case nothing, or `undefined`.

Here's a high level of how things are actually happening:

```
1) Create undefined var apiResponse
2) axios.get(...)
3) console.log(apiResponse)
4) #2 completes, assigns to `apiResponse`
5) End execution
```

Here's [one of many](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) resources about Promises.

Move the log statement inside the `.then()` block.

```
const axios = require('axios');

let apiResponse;

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(function(response) {
    apiResponse = response;
    console.log('Does this work?')
    console.log('apiResponse: ', apiResponse);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error, 'Error');
  });
```

Comment: I thought about that, but the log statement that's already inside the .get doesn't print. I don't think it's getting inside of that function for some reason.

Comment: I've never used axios, but I just ran your code and it works. http://requirebin.com/?gist=e00bc8e08eae1dbc8671ea86c4315c5d

Comment: That doesn't work for me either. Is it something with my dev environment?

Comment: Maybe. Can you put your project on github?

Comment: Forked and moved some stuff around: https://github.com/GeerSwitch/lob-coding-challenge

Comment: Yours works! Thank you! Can you explain why yours works and not mine? I understand that node is async, but should mine eventually log? How is that in your copy the get request always logs right after everything else?

Comment: Updated the README. Feel free to leave future communications on that repo.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help!